# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS no sound headphones

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones

I have a HP Spectre x360 , and I can't get any sound from the headphones. I have a dual boot with win10 and it works perfectly there.

In adition, i used to have audio before via headphones, and i recently updated to Ubunntu 18.04.2, perhaps it has something to do with this.
I've messed around with alsamixer and pavucontrol tweaking any possible combination but it doesn't work.

I can see with Pavucontrol that audio is detected (graphically) but no audio is sent through the headphones.

My specs:

```
         HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-w0XX

         Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

         Audio device

         product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: please check alsamixer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer Can you see headphone?   Have you check  for mute? ('M' key)